# Problema após atualização do Moodle 2.9 para 3.3.1 - Theme not designed for Moodle version

Tags: moodle

Após a atualização do Moodle versão 2.9 para Moodle 3.3.1+ (Build: 20170727), ocorre o seguinte erro abaixo:

> **Version warning:**  Theme not designed for Moodle version. Unexpected
>   issues may occur, please get the correct theme version for your Moodle
>   version.

Realizando algumas pesquisas, não obtive sucesso.

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Qual o Tema do moodle e qual versão esta utilizando, a mensagem diz que o seu tema do moodle não foi feito para sua versão do moodle. Talvez atualizando a versão do Tema resolva o problema (não entendo de moodle, nem nada do genero)

Comment: Sugiro procurar no diretório de temas do Moodle o tema compatível para a sua versão.
https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temas, assim como plugins do Moodle em geral, são compatíveis ou não com determinadas versões. Você pode tentar resolver isso:

- Atualizar a versão do tema para uma compatível com o Moodle e/ou;
- Removendo o diretório do tema do código do Moodle.

Você pode encontrar mais ajuda na comunidade oficial Moodle Brasil em https://moodle.org/course/view.php?id=35; e na base de plugins